# Слияние массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json

Имеется следующий код:

```
foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ){
$item_data = $item->get_data();
$data = array('Name' => $item_data['name'], 'Count' => $item_data['quantity'], 'Sum' => $item_data['total']);
// Получаем весь товар в формате массива
$tovari[] = $data;

}
//Если выбрана платная доставка, то включить в массив Goods (вместе с товарами - как товар)
$shipp = array('Name' => $order->get_shipping_method(), 'Count' => 1, 'Sum' => $order->order_shipping);

//Сливаем обе массива в одно целое
$massiv = array_merge($tovari, $shipp);
//Отправляем curl запрос (формате json - Application json)
$curlpost = array('Sign' => $matoken, 'Details' => [array('Sum' => $sum2, 'Product' => $massiv)]);
```

Проблема в заключается в том что после слияния обоих массивов получается следующий json запрос:

```
{"Sign":"318a3abba8916830a8db87f4ab","Details":[{"Sum":"350.00","ReceiptId":22,"Goods":{"0":{"Name":"Samsung","Count":1,"Sum":"200.00"},"1":{"Name":"Honor","Count":2,"Sum":"100.00"},"Name":"Доставка курьером","Count":1,"Sum":"50.00"}}]}
```

Правильная структура после слияния должна быть следующая:

```
{"Sign":"318a3abba8916830a8db87f4ab","Details":[{"Sum":"350.00","ReceiptId":22,"Goods":[{"Name":"Samsung","Count":1,"Sum":"200.00"},{"Name":"Honor","Count":2,"Sum":"100.00"},{"Name":"Доставка курьером","Count":1,"Sum":"50.00"}]}]}
```

Прошу Вас помочь решить данную проблему;

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, в вопросе, что именно отличается в json, чтобы не приходилось вчитываться и додумывать

Comment: "Goods":{"0":{"Name" <- неправильно сформирован, "Goods":[{"Name" <- правильно сформирован (но без  $shipp (без слияния)

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует использовать `array_push()` функцию в вашем случае:

Образец:

```
$array_main = array(
        0 => array(
            "Name" => "product1"
            )
    );
$need_to_add = array(
        "Name" => "Product2"
    );

array_push($array_main, $need_to_add);
var_dump($array_main);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Name' => string 'product1' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Name' => string 'Product2' (length=8)
```

В вашем случае вот так:

```
 //Сливаем обе массива в одно целое
    array_push($tovari, $shipp);
    //Отправляем curl запрос (формате json - Application json)
    $curlpost = array('Sign' => $matoken, 'Details' => [array('Sum' => $sum2, 'Product' => $tovari)]);
```

Надеюсь поможет.